# How does the @Results annotation of mybatis implement one-to-many mapping (do not use @one, @many annotations)

Tags: mybatis

How does the @Results annotation of mybatis implement one-to-many mapping (do not use @one, @many annotations. Because they will generate multiple sql statements).
I can do one-to-one result set mapping without @one annotation.

```
@Data
public class UserInfo {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String phone;

    private String mail;

    private Byte state;

    private Byte deleted;

    private String creator;

    private LocalDateTime createTime;

    private String updater;

    private LocalDateTime updateTime;

    private UserProfileRes userProfileRes;
}
```

```
@Data
public class UserProfileRes {

    private Long id;

    private Long userId;

    private String fullName;

    private Byte gender;

    private String ethnicity;

    private LocalDateTime birthday;

    private String idNumber;

    private String avatarUrl;

    private String bio;

    private String address;

    private String city;

    private String province;

    private String country;

    private String postalCode;
}
```

```
 @Results(id = "userResultMap", value = {
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
            @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),
            @Result(property = "phone", column = "phone"),
            @Result(property = "mail", column = "mail"),
            @Result(property = "state", column = "state"),
            @Result(property = "deleted", column = "deleted"),
            @Result(property = "creator", column = "creator"),
            @Result(property = "createTime", column = "create_time"),
            @Result(property = "updater", column = "updater"),
            @Result(property = "updateTime", column = "update_time"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.id", column = "up_id"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.userId", column = "user_id"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.fullName", column = "full_name"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.gender", column = "gender"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.ethnicity", column = "ethnicity"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.birthday", column = "birthday"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.idNumber", column = "id_number"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.avatarUrl", column = "avatar_url"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.bio", column = "bio"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.address", column = "address"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.city", column = "city"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.province", column = "province"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.country", column = "country"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileRes.postalCode", column = "postal_code")
    })
    @Select("select u.*,up.id up_id, user_id, full_name, gender, ethnicity, birthday, id_number, " +
            "avatar_url, bio, address, city, province, country, postal_code " +
            "from user u left join user_profile up on u.id = up.user_id where u.id = #{id} and u.deleted = #{deleted}")
    UserInfo selectUserInfo(Long id, Byte deleted);
```

The above is the way to complete the one-to-one mapping.But with one-to-many mapping, I'm completely clueless.

=======================================================================
via @ave's answer,I modified the code.it works,But there is an extra part of the code that I think is redundant.

```
@Data
public class UserInfo {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String phone;

    private String mail;

    private Byte state;

    private Byte deleted;

    private String creator;

    private LocalDateTime createTime;

    private String updater;

    private LocalDateTime updateTime;

    private List<UserProfileRes> userProfileResList;
}


@Data
public class UserProfileRes {

    private Long id;

    private Long userId;

    private String fullName;

    private Byte gender;

    private String ethnicity;

    private LocalDateTime birthday;

    private String idNumber;

    private String avatarUrl;

    private String bio;

    private String address;

    private String city;

    private String province;

    private String country;

    private String postalCode;
}


@Results(id = "userResultMap", value = {
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
            @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),
            @Result(property = "phone", column = "phone"),
            @Result(property = "mail", column = "mail"),
            @Result(property = "state", column = "state"),
            @Result(property = "deleted", column = "deleted"),
            @Result(property = "creator", column = "creator"),
            @Result(property = "createTime", column = "create_time"),
            @Result(property = "updater", column = "updater"),
            @Result(property = "updateTime", column = "update_time"),
            @Result(property = "userProfileResList", many = @Many(resultMap = "userProfileResultMap"))
    })
    @Select("select u.*,up.id up_id, user_id, full_name, gender, ethnicity, birthday, id_number, " +
            "avatar_url, bio, address, city, province, country, postal_code " +
            "from user u left join user_profile up on u.id = up.user_id where u.id = #{id} and u.deleted = #{deleted}")
    UserInfo selectUserInfo(Long id, Byte deleted);


     @Results(id = "userProfileResultMap", value = {
            @Result(property = "id", column = "up_id"),
            @Result(property = "userId", column = "user_id"),
            @Result(property = "fullName", column = "full_name"),
            @Result(property = "gender", column = "gender"),
            @Result(property = "ethnicity", column = "ethnicity"),
            @Result(property = "birthday", column = "birthday"),
            @Result(property = "idNumber", column = "id_number"),
            @Result(property = "avatarUrl", column = "avatar_url"),
            @Result(property = "bio", column = "bio"),
            @Result(property = "address", column = "address"),
            @Result(property = "city", column = "city"),
            @Result(property = "province", column = "province"),
            @Result(property = "country", column = "country"),
            @Result(property = "postalCode", column = "postal_code")
    })
    @Select("select up.id up_id, user_id, full_name, gender, ethnicity, birthday, id_number, " +
            "avatar_url, bio, address, city, province, country, postal_code from user_profile")
    List<UserProfileRes> selectUserProfile();
```

I wrote a method List selectUserProfile() that I didn't need just for the @Results with `id="userProfileResultMap".

========================== final version ============================
The entity class remains the same as the original.

```
@Results(id = "userResultMap", value = {
       @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
       @Result(property = "userProfileResList", many = @Many(resultMap = "com.dsy.springcloud.user.mapper.UserProfileMapper.userProfileResListMap"))
    })
    @Select("select u.*,up.id up_id, user_id, full_name, gender, ethnicity, birthday, id_number, " +
            "avatar_url, bio, address, city, province, country, postal_code " +
            "from user u left join user_profile up on u.id = up.user_id where u.id = #{id} and u.deleted = #{deleted}")
    UserInfo selectUserInfo(Long id, Byte deleted);


     @Results(id = "userProfileResultMap", value = {
                       @Result(property = "id", column = "up_id",id = true),
    })
    @Select("select up.id up_id, user_id, full_name, gender, ethnicity, birthday, id_number, " +
            "avatar_url, bio, address, city, province, country, postal_code from user_profile")
    List<UserProfileRes> selectUserProfile();
```

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to map ["nested result"](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#nested-results-for-collection) using annotation, this [test](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/5d51f64b9cf81f73c235b79fcd2ca17e089728df/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/annotion_many_one_add_columnprefix/UserDao.java#L30-L42) shows you how. Note that it requires a recent version of MyBatis (3.5.5+, the latest is 3.5.13).

Comment: Thanks, your answer works. But is there a more concise way of writing it.Please see my re-edited question for specific questions.

Comment: Yes, it's currently necessary to define the extra method just for defining result map. Usually, such a method is used in somewhere else (that's where the `columnPrefix` comes in handy), but not always.

Comment: If the column names and property names match, you may be able to omit most of the `@Result`s by setting `mapUnderscoreToCamelCase=true` and `autoMappingBehavior=FULL` in [config](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#settings). Note that you still need `@Result` entries with `id=true` to map parent-child relationship correctly. Also, relying on auto-mapping could impose performance penalty as there are more things for MyBatis to figure out compared to the explicit mapping.

Comment: Many thanks 
```@Select("select up.id up_id, user_id, full_name, gender, ethnicity, birthday, id_number, " +
             "avatar_url, bio, address, city, province, country, postal_code from user_profile")
 List<UserProfileRes> selectUserProfile();
```
the above code is necessary, right?
See if my final version is the easiest.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that you will never use the `selectUserProfile()` method, you don't have to write the proper SQL actually (e.g. `@Select("nope")` works just fine). BTW, if you are open to using XML, you can remove the extra method `selectUserProfile` and its annotations by defining the `userProfileResultMap` in XML. You don't have to change the `selectUserInfo()` method or its annotations.

Comment: Thank you, but at present I feel that the introduction of xml increases the complexity of the code, so I have been looking for a way to map complex objects in annotations.